# При селекте из бд берется один и тот же элемент

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Имеется таблица, где под одним идешником могут быть записаны несколько значений (там строка). Найти идешник по значению получается, но найти по идешнику все значения не получается, точнее я получаю `List<Entity> selected_rows`, в котором записываются все совпадения и я могу узнать количество совпадений (`.size()`), но в значение каждого элемента листа записывается первое совпадение, пример:

```
name = Avrora, id = 15
name = Avrora, id = 15
name = Avrora, id = 15
name = Avrora, id = 15
```

А если в постгресе сделать запрос select where `id = 15`

```
name = Avrora, id = 15
name = Aaao, id = 15
name = Circle, id = 15
name = Ddddd, id = 15
```

Почему так получается?

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = dbSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Entity> query = builder.createQuery(Entity.class);
    Root<Entity> root = query.from(Entity.class);
    query.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
    List<Entity> selected_rows = dbSession.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

В JPA поменял `@Id` от `id` на `name`, т.к в моем случае `id` не уникален, а `name` уникален.